# Compare groups of rows within two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a way to find the Aisle where the CLOSEST Rack (the Rack with the lowest number) can fit the items to be stored (itemsToBeStored) on the respective shelves. For context see below:

```
import pandas as pd

ExampleOfTheStock = {'Aisle':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        'Rack':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       'Shelves':['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
        'SpaceInLiters':[1, 2, 1, 9, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1, 1, 9, 9]}

ItemsToBeStored = {'Items':[1, 2],
        'VolumeInLiters':[2, 8]}

DesiredResult = {'WinnerAisle':[1, 1, 1], # because it fits in rack 2 in aisle 1, which is lower than rack 3 in aisle 2.
        'WinnerRack':[2, 2, 2],
       'WinnerShelves':['A', 'B', None], # could also be 'C' if that is easier.
        'WinnerSpaceInLiters':[1, 2, 9], # 9 - 8 = 1 | 4 - 2 = 2 | 9 - Nan = 0
        'StoredItems': [1, 2, None]} 

# Create DataFrame
ExampleOfTheStock = pd.DataFrame(ExampleOfTheStock)
ItemsToBeStored = pd.DataFrame(ItemsToBeStored)

# Desired output
DesiredResult = pd.DataFrame(DesiredResult)
DesiredResult
```

CONTEXT

Aisles contain Racks, and Racks contain shelves. Articles can only be placed on shelves where there is place. We want to put stuff in the rack that is closest to the spur, which is in the example expressed as a number, where lower is more close. You cannot go from aisle to aisle.

Answer (score 0):

if someone has something to add to my solution, please do so!

```
def getTheFirstEmptyRackThatFitsTheItems(stockDataframe, toteDataframe):
    toteDataframe['totalVolume'] = toteDataframe.volume * toteDataframe.quantity
    numberOfSKU = len(toteDataframe)
    toteDataframe = toteDataframe.sort_values('totalVolume', ascending = False)#.reset_index()
#         print(toteDataframe)
    for itemNumber in range(0, numberOfSKU):
        print(toteDataframe.iloc[itemNumber].totalVolume)
        stockDataframe[f'{itemNumber}volume'] = toteDataframe.iloc[itemNumber].totalVolume
        stockDataframe[f"{itemNumber}Fits"] = (stockDataframe.SpaceInLiters >= stockDataframe[f'{itemNumber}volume'])
        print(stockDataframe)
        stockDataframeGrouped = stockDataframe.groupby(['Aisle', 'Rack']).sum().reset_index()
        print(stockDataframeGrouped)
        stockDataframeSelection = stockDataframeGrouped[stockDataframeGrouped[f"{itemNumber}Fits"] >= numberOfSKU]
        
        # check if still possible
        maxSKUThatFit = stockDataframeGrouped[f"{itemNumber}Fits"].max()
        if maxSKUThatFit <= itemNumber:
            return 'This tote cannot be putawayed'
        
        print(stockDataframeSelection)
        if len(stockDataframeSelection) > 0:
            return stockDataframeSelection.sort_values(by=['Rack', 'Aisle']).head(1)

getTheFirstEmptyRackThatFitsTheItems(ExampleOfTheStockSpace, ItemsToBeStored)
```